# Converting from PixelBuffer to Image in UWP C# (Using only Windows.UI.Xaml)

Tags: c#, image, uwp, buffer, pixel

Hi all I want to convert pixel buffer to image and print it. This is information that I have in my program:
PixelBuffer: int width, int height, IntPtr buffer, stride. This is how I cannot do it because of some assembly errors:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image image = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image();
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame frame = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.Create(
                        (int)pr.pixelBuffer.width,
                        (int)pr.pixelBuffer.height,
                        96,
                        96,
                        System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Rgb24,
                        null,
                        pr.pixelBuffer.buffer,
                        (int)(pr.pixelBuffer.stride * pr.pixelBuffer.height),
                        (int)pr.pixelBuffer.stride));
Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(frame.BaseUri);
image.Source = bitmapImage;//frame;
stackPanel.Children.Add(image)
```

Is there any way to do this without System.Windowxs.Media.Imaging? Using only Windows.UI.Xaml ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use *BitmapEncoder* instead of bitmap frame?

Comment: WriteableImage can be set  Pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to convert pixel buffer to image and print it.

I'm not sure what your pixel buffer come from since your code only shows getting from `pr` obejct. In uwp app
if you got it from [`Writeable​Bitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap) instance, you may not need to get pixel buffer firstly, just set the `WriteableBitmap` as the [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Image_Source) of image. Both [`Bitmap​Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage) and `WriteableBitmap` can be the image source, not only `BitmapImage`.

```
StorageFile imagefile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/caffe1.jpg"));
WriteableBitmap writeableimage;
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await imagefile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap;
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
    softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
    writeableimage = new WriteableBitmap(softwareBitmap.PixelWidth, softwareBitmap.PixelHeight);
    writeableimage.SetSource(stream);
}
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image image = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image();
image.Source = writeableimage;
stackPanel.Children.Add(image);
```

If it doesn't from `WriteableBitmap`, you may need to create a `WriteableBitmap` with the known width, height, and write pixel data to it.

```
StorageFile imagefile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/caffe2.jpg"));
int width;
int height;
byte[] Inptrbuffer;
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await imagefile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap;
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
    softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
    width = softwareBitmap.PixelWidth;
    height = softwareBitmap.PixelHeight;
    Windows.Graphics.Imaging.PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
    Inptrbuffer = pixelData.DetachPixelData(); 
}
WriteableBitmap newfrompixel=new WriteableBitmap(width,height);
using (Stream stream = newfrompixel.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(Inptrbuffer, 0, Inptrbuffer.Length);
} 
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image image = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image(); 
image.Source = newfrompixel; 
stackPanel.Children.Add(image);
```

If you need to edit the image before present it, please reference [Create, edit, and save bitmap images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging).

Comment: Thanks for reply!
Actually I do edit my photo in native C and then in return I get information as mentioned in PixelBuffer in my C# application, so I need to convert PixelBuffer into Image, or stream just from PixelBuffer Data, I don't have StorageFile or similar things

Comment: @user7827649, so as I said above, "If it doesn't from WriteableBitmap, you may need to create a WriteableBitmap with the known width, height, and write pixel data to it." Please check the code snippet on the second parts. By the way, if my answer helped you please mark as accepted.

Comment: I had a problem because I have removed alpha channel from picture/ or it is because of picture's stride, I still don't know, but your solution is correct and it is what I have been looking for.
Thank you !!

Comment: @user7827649, open a new thread if you still have new issues. Maybe provide some screenshots to clear the issue. Thanks.